# How to fail Jenkins pipeline stage status, after stage finished success

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to fail Jenkins pipeline stage status, after stage finished success.
Please help
thank you

```
def build_job_result = [:]
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                build_job_result = build job: "jobName", wait: false
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                  def jobName   = build_job_result.getFullDisplayName().split()[0]
                  def jobNumber = build_job_result.number
                  def jobStatus = build_job_result.getStatus()

                  if (jobStatus == failed) {
                     stage('1').status = failed
                   }
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you are out of a stage you can't change the stage status AFAIK. The better option is to refactor your Pipeline to something like below. Basically, run your stages in parallel.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Parallel Example') {
            parallel {
                stage('1') {
                    steps {
                        build_job_result = build job: "jobName", wait: true
                        if (build_job_result == failed) {
                            error "Build Failed"
                         }
                    }
                }
                
                stage('2') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'Do something else while the job runs'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```